# importing android studio 1.2 project to android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, importerror

i upgraded to android studio 3.0 from android studio 1.2
currently  i cannot work on any of my old projects on android 3.0, been getting a lot of gradle build errors
example
Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.2.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Gradle settings

Comment: You need to change the gradle version from 2.2.1 to 3.3. you can do it by editing gradle file

Comment: okay, in the project.gradle file?

Comment: Yes@petyr......

Comment: Run your existing project, it asks for required update. Download all the link which is showing in Logcat. The gradle, dependencies are upgraded automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Android Studio 3.0 using `Gradle-4.1` and
>   `Android-gradle-plugin 3.0.0`

Find gradle folder inside your project

Open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Open root `build.gradle` file and change in buildscript

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Additionally you need to add `google()` repo link in project repositories list and buildScript repo list.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    jcenter()
    google()        //<-   Add
}
```

Comment: Adding `google()` helped me import Android Studio 2.* project into Android Studio 3.4